# Extraction of the coefficient in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am using MALAB and I have a function of symbolic x as follows

6/(5*(1/x^3 + 1))

What function in MATLAB should I use so that I can extract the coefficient 6/5?

I tried using **coeffs** but that does not work

Comment: is the structure of the symbolic expression always `a/(b*(1/X^3+1))` ?

Comment: @bla yes how does it matter though?

Comment: @George: If you don't know the structure, we won't know what to extract!!!

Comment: @knedlsepp I see, but yes its the same as what bla mentioned.

Comment: @George: Then please reformulate your question in that manner.

Comment: @knedlsepp I think its clear.

Comment: You can't use `coeffs` because `coeffs` assumes that the input is a polynomial expression.  The above is not so.

Comment: yup agreed but dont know how to fix it.@rayryeng

Comment: @rayryeng forgot to tag :)

Comment: @George, it matters because your question is not well phrased. otherwise I wouldn't have asked.

Comment: @George: It could be `a/(b*(c/X^d+e))` or even more complicated. It is definitely **NOT** clear! And you being too lazy to fix it doesn't help either.

Answer (score 2):

For the general form mentioned in the comments `a/(b*(1/x^n+1))`, you can extract the leading coefficient by setting `x` to `Inf` or taking it's limit (the more mathematically correct path):

```
syms a b x;
n = sym('n','positive');
aoverb1 = limit(a/(b*(1/x^n+1),x,Inf);
aoverb2 = subs (a/(b*(1/x^n+1),x,Inf);
```

For the specific case, you can use number literals and the return value will be symbolic:

```
>> subs(6/(5*(1/x^3 + 1)),x,Inf)
ans =
6/5
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is confusing, but maybe this can help. I'm interpreting the question as follows: you have an expression with powers of *x*. Those powers may habe positive or negative exponents. You want the coefficient of the term with the largest exponent.

If that's the case: transform your expression to numerator and denominator, and what you want is the highest-order order coefficient of numerator divided by the lowest-order coefficient of denominator.

I show intermediate results for clarity:

```
>> syms x;
>> y = 6/(5*(1/x^3 + 1));
>> [num, den] = numden(y)
num =
6*x^3
den =
5*x^3 + 5

>> cnum = coeffs(num)
cnum =
6
>> cden = coeffs(den)
cden =
[ 5, 5]

>> result = cnum(1)/cden(end)
result =
6/5
```